# Preserve formula references when printing a single Google Sheets sheet to PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas, export-to-pdf

I want to accomplish the following:

1. Make a menu with a print to PDF button.
2. Have that button export a PDF to with the same name and same destination as the google sheet.

This works well, but the script I found I need to change, because most people print to PDF by making a temporary copy of the sheet, printing, and finally deleting the temporary copy.

I have references from other sheets in my original document that ends up printed as **`#REF!`** values because only the one sheet gets copied and printed, not my whole document.

How can i make this process include baking the formulas as text?

**CODE FOR PRINTING:**

```
function onOpen() {
  var submenu = [{name: "Save PDF", functionName: "generatePdf"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Export', submenu);  
}

function generatePdf() {
  // Get active spreadsheet.
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Get active sheet.
  var sheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  var sheetName = sourceSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Set the output filename as sheetName.
  var pdfName = sheetName;

  // Get folder containing spreadsheet to save pdf in.
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).getParents();
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
    var folder = parents.next();
  }
  else {
    folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }

  // Copy whole spreadsheet.
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

  // Delete redundant sheets.
  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
      destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }

  var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

  // Replace cell values with text (to avoid broken references).
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceSheet.getMaxRows(), sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
  var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
  destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

  // Save to pdf.
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

  // Delete the temporary sheet.
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

**CODE FOR CONVERTING FORMULAS TO TEXT:**

```
function formulasAsText() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var k = 0; k < sheets.length; k++) {
    var range = sheets[k].getDataRange();
    var values = range.getValues();
    var formulas = range.getFormulas();
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++) {
        values[i][j] = formulas[i][j] ? "'" + formulas[i][j] : values[i][j];
      }
    }
    range.setValues(values);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried simply hiding the other sheets, then generating the PDF, then unhiding the ones that were hidden?

Comment: No, i did not know that was possible. Do you have a tip to push in the right direction?

Comment: use Apps Script documentation / API reference and editor autocomplete to find the methods you need. The process is outlined in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To maintain formula references, you need to modify the `formulasAsText()` function to accept an input, and also not worry about writing a formula if one is found. This input could be a spreadsheet ID - i.e. the `id` of the temporary copy - or it could be an array of `Sheet` objects.

Once you have made these two modifications, you would call the function prior to deleting the non-desired sheets in the temporary copy:

```
/**
 * @param Sheet[] wbSheets     An array of Sheets to operate on.
 * @param String  toPreserve   The name of the sheet which should be preserved.
 */
function preserveFormulas(wbSheets, toPreserve) {
  if(!wbSheets || !wbSheets.length || !toPreserve)
    throw new Error("Missing arguments.");

  wbSheets.forEach(function (sheet) {
    if ( sheet.getName() === toPreserve ) {
      var range = sheet.getDataRange();
      // Serialize the cell's current value, be it static or derived from a formula.
      range.setValues(range.getValues());
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finished my script. Here is what i ended up with.

```
function onOpen() {
  var submenu = [{name:"Save PDF", functionName:"generatePdf"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Export', submenu);  
}

function hideSheets() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("PRINT SHEET");
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet3");
  var sheet4 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet4");
  var sheet5 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet5");
  var sheet6 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet6");
  var sheet7 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet7");

  sheet1.hideSheet();
  sheet3.hideSheet();
  sheet4.hideSheet();
  sheet5.hideSheet();
  sheet6.hideSheet();
  sheet7.hideSheet();

}

function showSheets() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("PRINT SHEET");
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet3");
  var sheet4 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet4");
  var sheet5 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet5");
  var sheet6 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet6");
  var sheet7 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet7");

  sheet1.showSheet();
  sheet3.showSheet();
  sheet4.showSheet();
  sheet5.showSheet();
  sheet6.showSheet();
  sheet7.showSheet();

}

function generatePdf() {

  // Get active spreadsheet.
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Get active sheet.
  var sheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  var sheetName = sourceSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Set the output filename as BID and number (from cell C4).
  var pdfName = "BID " + sheets[0].getRange("C4").getValue() + ".pdf";


  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // Get folder containing spreadsheet to save pdf in.
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).getParents();
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
    var folder = parents.next();
  }
  else {
    folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }

  hideSheets();

  // Save to pdf.
  var theBlob = sourceSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);



  showSheets();
  ui.alert('Export finished');
}
```

Thanks.